# Converting Array of Boolean Values to Separate Rows for Days, Start Time, and End Time in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

My dataset looks something like this:

[image]

Each element in daysBitArray denotes day of the week with index 0 being Monday. So for SnobbyChckenWings restaurant start time and end time are "00:00" and "23:59" resepctively for all the days.

Now I want to convert this dataset into something like this:

[image]

Comment: Ankit: From site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: in short there is a disincentive to answer your question if we are expected to unpack images (when we also know you have that data in text form).  copy/paste is better than images and/or try sites like this: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 0):

This should work I believe however it is untested. It "unnests" the array into rows and then the case expression converts the row number to a day name. I have also included output of the true/false value from the source array as that might also be required.

```
SELECT
  , vb_name
  , CASE day_struct.day
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Saturday'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Sunday'
     END AS dayOfWeek
  , day_struct.available AS isAvailable
  , startTime
  , endTime
FROM yourtable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
     ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER () - 1 AS day
          , dayBit AS available
        FROM UNNEST(daysBitArray) AS dayBit
        )
    ) AS day_struct
```

Comment: Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type JSON.

Somehow it is treating daysBitArray as a JSON object. Any idea how would I convert it to array?

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL) - assuming `daysBitArray` is actually JSON Array rather then just Array

```
select vb_name as name, day, startTime as start, endTime as `end`
from your_table t,
unnest(json_extract_array(daysBitArray)) as bit with offset
join unnest(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']) as day with offset
using(offset)
where bit = 'true'
order by name, offset
```

Comment: The only change needed was JSON_VALUE(bit) = 'true'. 

Thank you!